# Need to add contents of a cell into an email subject line (gsheets)

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm new to using the google script, but I do have some experience with simple coding.  I have created a gsheet that my employees will be using as a form to submit information after the completion of a flight.  I found a script that emails the form as PDF, which works great.  What I need is to modify the script so that the flight number is included in the subject line of the email, and the content of certain cells are cleared once the script has run.  The flight number is entered on the gsheet in cell H26.  I would appreciate any help.  Thanks.  The code I am using and need to modify is below.

```
function submitform() {
  // Send the PDF of the spreadsheet to this email address
  var email = "myemail"; 

  // Get the currently active spreadsheet URL (link)
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // Subject of email message
  var subject = "Flight Debrief";

  // Email Body can  be HTML too 
  var body = "Post Flight Debrief";

  var blob = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).getAs("application/pdf");

  blob.setName(ss.getName() + ".pdf");

  // If allowed to send emails, send the email with the PDF attachment
  if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0) 
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
      htmlBody: body,
      attachments:[blob]     
    });
}
```

Comment: This isn't the place to ask others to find a script for you but it's for asking for help if got stuck on writing/adapting an script. Have you already tried the class [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)?

Comment: I apologize.  I was told to come to this platform for help.  I have not tried that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include the cell data in the subject, first you need to pull the data from the desired cell:

Add: `var fltNbr = ss.getRange("H26").getValue();`

Add the `fltNbr` variable to the email subject variable:
`var subject = "Flight Debrief";` becomes `var subject = fltNbr + " Flight Debrief";` (notice the space before 'Flight' for "pretty" formatting...)

Use [Clear Contents of a range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearContent()) to determine how to clear the cells you want.

Comment: @Ryan P. Owen, please accept this answer if it provided what you need, or let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!